# Find matches from 5 lists based on matches condition

Tags: c#, list

Given I have a model that looks like this:

```
public sealed class BaseInfo
    {
        public string ValueToBeMatched { get; set; }

        public string CreatedValue { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have variables that initialized the `BaseInfo` class like the following:

```
List<BaseInfo> zeroBaseInfo = new List<BaseInfo>
{
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "001",
      CreatedValue = "2008-10-10"
   },
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "003",
      CreatedValue = "2007-10-10"
   },
}

List<BaseInfo> firstBaseInfo = new List<BaseInfo>
{
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "002",
      CreatedValue = "2006-10-10"
   },
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "001",
      CreatedValue = "2008-10-10"
   },
}

List<BaseInfo> secondBaseInfo= new List<BaseInfo>
{
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "001",
      CreatedValue = "2008-10-10"
   },
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "002",
      CreatedValue = "2006-10-10"
   },
}

List<BaseInfo> thirdBaseInfo = new List<BaseInfo>
{
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "002",
      CreatedValue = "2006-10-10"
   },
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "001",
      CreatedValue = "2008-10-10"
   },
}

List<BaseInfo> fourthBaseInfo = new List<BaseInfo>
{
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "",
      CreatedValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
   },
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "001",
      CreatedValue = "2008-10-10"
   },
}
```

The condition is the 5 lists have to matches with 2 matches or more with each other, then it will store into the new list for the result of it.

I am thinking about using the for loop for each lists and make the if statement in the each loop matched with condition with each index of list. But I am stuck.

Here is the code that I am stuck on:

```
for (int i = 0; i < zeroBaseInfo.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < firstBaseInfo.Count; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < secondBaseInfo.Count; k++)
                    {
                        for (int o = 0; o < thirdBaseInfo.Count; o++)
                        {
                            for (int p = 0; p < fourthBaseInfo.Count; p++)
                            {
                                // I am stuck in this point to what needs to be compare, as if statement only works against comparison value between 1 to 1 and not all of lists.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**EDIT:**

Expected Output:

```
List<BaseInfo> matchedNewLists = new List<BaseInfo>
{
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "001",
      CreatedValue = "2006-10-10"
   },
   new BaseInfo
   {
      ValueToBeMatched = "002",
      CreatedValue = "2008-10-10"
   }
}
```

Since `001` and `002` is fulfilled the condition (2 matches or more) within the 5 lists above

Any help and your answer much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is confusing, give an example of the desired output

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong - The condition is the 5 lists have to matches with 2 matches or more with each other, then it will store into the new list for the result of it. - Means, any two lists must match out of 5 and the matching list has to be added to new result list. Correct? If this is correct then does each element in the list you are expecting to match or at-least one item in the list is sufficient to match?

Comment: Hi @TheGeneral, I have edited the question for includes the Expected Output. Please kindly check. Thanks

Comment: Hi @GK, yes you are correct and the list have to be at least one item is sufficient to match, I have include the Expected Output as well in the question above. Please kindly check for your reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a few LINQ operations. I have split them up to make it clear what I am doing here:

```
var oneLongList = new[] { zeroBaseInfo, firstBaseInfo, secondBaseInfo, thirdBaseInfo, fourthBaseInfo }.SelectMany(x => x);
var allValuesToBeMatched = oneLongList.Select(x => x.ValueToBeMatched);
var grouped = allValuesToBeMatched.GroupBy(x => x);
var filtered = grouped.Where(x => x.Count() >= 2).Select(x => x.Key);
var finalResult = filtered.Select(x => new BaseInfo { ValueToBeMatched = x });
```

Or you can combine them all in one:

```
var finalResult = new[] { zeroBaseInfo, firstBaseInfo, secondBaseInfo, thirdBaseInfo, fourthBaseInfo }
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .Select(x => x.ValueToBeMatched)
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() >= 2)
    .Select(x => new BaseInfo { ValueToBeMatched = x.Key });
```

EDIT:

```
var finalResult = new[] { zeroBaseInfo, firstBaseInfo, secondBaseInfo, thirdBaseInfo, fourthBaseInfo }
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ValueToBeMatched)
    .Where(x => x.Count() >= 2)
    .Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, thanks for your answer, if you don't mind, if I want to return the `CreatedValue` as well like in the question above, how can I do that? as from the LINQ, you only select the `ValueToBeMatched`, and when I just `SelectMany(x => x)` or `Select(x => x)`, it will be `IEnumerable<BaseInfo>` instead. Thanks

Comment: @Reinhardt Well, there are many `CreatedValue`s. Which one do you want to return?

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, I have updated the question to include each of the item in the lists to be have unique Date, and as well what do I want it to be return and set into the new list when I have matched based on the condition. Thanks

Comment: @Reinhardt You mean for any 2 `BaseInfo` objects, if their `ValueToBeMatched` are the same, their `CreatedValue` are guaranteed be the same as well?

Comment: @Reinhardt if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq.

```
List<BaseInfo> matchedNewLists = 
                zeroBaseInfo
                .Union(firstBaseInfo)
                .Union(secondBaseInfo)
                .Union(thirdBaseInfo)
                .Union(fourthBaseInfo)
                .GroupBy(bi => new { bi.ValueToBeMatched, bi.CreatedValue})
                .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                .Select(grp => 
                        new BaseInfo()
                        {
                            ValueToBeMatched = grp.Key.ValueToBeMatched,
                            CreatedValue = grp.Key.CreatedValue
                        })
                .ToList();
```